# Automatic determination of free versus fixed form Fortran code

Tags: fortran

I need to know, for a public domain package, if given Fortran code is free of fixed formatted code and it is, unfortunately, not possible to use the extension for this. Is there a reliable way to do this / is there example code that does this?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question... Do you want to determine it automatically, i,e. not by (manually) looking at the code?

Comment: Yes, I have to determine it automatically.

Comment: I know of no quick&easy solution... I would try two things: compile it as free-form, and if that fails using fixed-from (you could script that for every file). Or, you could write a script that checks the source code, e.g. whether the first columns conform with the fixed form, and whether lines are not longer than 72 columns. If that fails, it is free-form.

Comment: I cannot use a compiler, I need it it in a documentation system that tries to do its own parsing. Your second solution is something that I'm looking for, but I haven't found a reliable way to do this. Just checking the first column and/or length of 72 is not sufficient.

Comment: Fortran code can be both valid free source form and valid fixed source form -- Cray calls this "portable source form" http://docs.cray.com/books/007-3692-005/html-007-3692-005/hu2ulchri.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to write your own program/script that checks the form.

Is there any `&` before column 72 outside of character strings? -> free form

Is there any non-number in the first columns outside of comments? -> free form

There other possibilities, but they would generally have to be able to decide if the statement is valid and that is more difficult:

Deciding if the character in column is a continuation character or a part of a statement in the free-form.

Deciding if a non-`!` character in the first column is a comment in the fixed form or a valid statement in the free form.

There may be files that conform to both, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The rule: "Is a non ! used as a comment sign in the first column? -> fixed form" does not hold e.g. the word CHARACTER is possible to start in the first column.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [this](https://wwwasdoc.web.cern.ch/wwwasdoc/WWW/f90/convert.f90) program. It is supposed to convert FORTRAN code into Fortran 90 code. A lot of the rules/transformations applied there might be useful for your script!

Comment: @albert that's true it should be in the group where you have to decide about the validity of the statement. But I wrote as a comment sign, not any non `!` character in the first column.

Comment: I think you need to look for both comments and continuation because you may very well have cases which have none of one or the other.  I'd think looking for "c " would catch the vast majority, and in the end do you really care about pathological examples?

Comment: & is valid in column 6 of fixed-form source. I'll also comment that there's a LOT of fixed-form source that goes past column 72, relying on compiler options to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Silverfrost FTN95 uses the file extension:

```
.for, .f or .fix - fixed format
.f90 .f95 - free format
```

If the user wants to override the default they use a command line option (which they can also turn on-off as a default)

You could use these extensions as a first guess and then look at the first few lines and see if they match

Comment: *it is, unfortunately, not possible to use the extension for this*